# PDF output is different after copying code into new file and compling

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker, moderncv

I received a code for a CV from a professor of mine, which I intended to replace the information in and use as a template. Here is the code (after I replaced the original information with my own):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\moderncvstyle{banking} \moderncvcolor{black}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{23}{1}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{23}{1}\mdseries\upshape}
\usepackage[scale=0.76]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Hancock}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\email{example@gmail.com}
\phone{(123) 456-789}
\address{123 Blue Drive, Albany NY}{USA}{}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{EDUCATION}
\vspace{1pt}
\cventry{}{}{BSc, ABC, Science University}{2021 (Candidate)}{}
    {Thesis title: \textit{Name of thesis} \\ Supervisor: John Doe}{}

\vspace{.7em}  

\end{document}
```

Compiling this file produced an identical format to the original CV my professor sent me. However, I copied the code into a new tab of my editor, saved it as a new file, and compiled again. This time, the output was different (see images 1 and 2). Is there any reason this might be the case? The output in the second image was also produced when compiling the code in another LaTeX editor, so it seems that editing the original `.tex` file I received is the only way to produce the output I desire.

Before and after copying & compiling in new file:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should check if you compile usinh the `same version`  packages

Comment: compare the log-files of the two compilations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I checked the log files and there are several differences between the two, mostly stemming from the fact that the log file for the original has many extra lines. I'm not sure where to go from here, is there anything I should be looking for in particular? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Denis Sorry, I'm new to `Tex`, How would I go about doing this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `\listfiles` and check the log file.

Comment: @Denis I looked at the log files. For the original file, many packages are relying on previous versions. For example, `moderncv.cls`, `moderncvcompatibility.sty`, `moderncvstylebanking.sty` are all from 2012 in the original and 2015 in the newer. All my packages are up to date in MikTeX, so perhaps the original file is reading the older versions from the zip file I was sent with the CV and its associated files. Do you know how to get the original file to use the new packages? Part of my problem is that I like the original file's visual look but I'm worried about future compatibility issues.

Comment: @A.B. You have found the reason for the differences in output. I think you should stick to the up to date versions.

Comment: @ Unfortunately I can't as the newer versions make it difficult to have the output appear as desired (mostly issues with vertical spacing, and the size of the vertical line in the title). If I did use the newer versions, would you happen to know how to fix this? Or perhaps if I use the older version, you may be able to answer my question here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555321/remove-blank-line-in-moderncv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 1.x to 2.x was a **major incompatible code changing** between the two versions. That means that the layout differs between this two versions (also some command names changed ...).

So if I compile your given code with the original version 1.2 of `moderncv` (see log file) I get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

with the first lines from the log file created:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.7.14)  7 AUG 2020 11:41
entering extended mode
**./554866.tex
(554866.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18> (moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
```

As you can see, your two immages differ to mine image. **I think your professor changed some code inside the class file or sty files ...**

Your code compiled with the original and current version 2.0.0 of `moderncv` results in

[image: second resulting pdf]

which is the same image you have on the right in your question.

With the first lines from the log file created:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.7.14)  7 AUG 2020 11:38
entering extended mode
**./554866.tex
(554866.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/moderncv\moderncv.cls"
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
```

To be able to use the version your professor gave you copy all given files into a new directory. Then copy your given MWE into the same directory, for example with filename `mwe.tex`, and compile it. Now you can check the logfile to see, that your local class and style files are used.

The **advantage** is you have the layout your professor wants.

The **disadvantage** is that we do not see the changed code and can you not help you more (or do you have an link to the zip file your professor gave you?)