# Remove blank line in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm currently creating a CV with `moderncv` in Overleaf. I'm using `pdfLaTeX` and the 2014 (Legacy) version of TeX Live. (I am trying to reuse a template from my professor which displays incorrectly if using a more recent version). There are still a few problems I am having with getting my output to display correctly. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.76]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé tite}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{EMPLOYMENT}
\vspace{1pt}
\cventry{}{}{Assistant Professor}{Since March 2020}{}{Department 
        of LaTeX, Science University}{}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{EDUCATION}
\vspace{1pt}
\cventry{}{}{PhD, Science University}{2019}{}
        {Thesis title: \textit{Lorem Ipsum} \\ Supervisor: Jacob Smith}{}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to be able to increase the vertical space between the title line and the address line. I would also like to remove the blank lines between the bolded text and the normal text underneath (e.g. "Assistant Professor" and "Department of LaTeX, Science University").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to be able to increase the vertical space between the title line and the address line.

If you are using `banking` style of moderncv, the definition of `\makehead` is defined in `moderncvheadiii.sty` as follows:

```
\@initializecommand{\makehead}{%
  \setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\makeheaddetailswidth}{%
    \centering%
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\
    \if@details{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscity}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
        
...

}
```

So all what you need to do is to hack this to insert some vertical space between `\\` and `\if@details`. This is all the hack you need to do around `\makecvtitle` in your document:

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\if@detailsoriginal\if@details
\def\if@details{\vskip1.0\baselineskip\if@detailsoriginal}
\makecvtitle
\let\if@details\if@detailsoriginal
\makeatother
```

You can change the space amount by modifying the value of `1.0\baselineskip`.

Result: [image: Reult]

---

> I would also like to remove the blank lines between the bolded text and the normal text underneath (e.g. "Assistant Professor" and "Department of LaTeX, Science University").

If you are using `banking` style of moderncv, the definition of `\cventry` is defined in `moderncvbodyiii.sty` as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
        
  ...
  
  }
```

You see a tabular* environment inside. So what you need to do is to change `\arraystretch`. For example, if you write this in your preamble you can smash the interline between the bolded text and the normal text by setting the stretch zero:

```
\let\cventryoriginal\cventry
\def\cventry#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\bgroup\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}\cventryoriginal{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}\egroup}
```

Result: [image: Result]

Again, you can change the amount of vertical space by modifying the value of `\arraystretch{0}`.

---

Update: as for moderncv 2012 ver.

The title command `\makecvtitle` calls for `\maketitle` which is defined in moderncvstylebanking.sty as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
    \centering%
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@title}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}\flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}

...

}
```

So all what you need to do is to hack this to insert some vertical space between `\\` and `\addressfont`. This is all the hack you need to do around `\makecvtitle` in your document:

```
\begin{document}
\let\addressfontoriginal\addressfont
\def\addressfont{\vskip1.0\baselineskip\addressfontoriginal}
\makecvtitle
\let\addressfont\addressfontoriginal
```

You can change the space amount by modifying the value of `1.0\baselineskip`.

Comment: @AboAmmer your style of banking 2014 seems a slightly different from my style of banking 2017. e.g. yours does not have an empty line between address and phone number while mine does as a default. I suppose, however, that my solution would work as well on yours. Good luK!

Comment: Thanks for you help! I tried both codes and they work! I managed to fix the second problem, but I'm still having trouble with the first problem. Unfortunately, the first code you gave only works with newer versions of Tex Live, which I am unable to use because of display issues when I run my code with newer versions. Would you happen to know how to make a similar hack with the 2014 (or earlier) version of  `moderncv`? I think the relevant definitions are in `moderncvstylebanking.sty` as `moderncvheadiii.sty` did not exist at the time.

Comment: Edit: It's line 103 in `moderncvstylebanking.sty` for `moderncv` version 1.2.0. https://launchpad.net/moderncv/+milestone/1.2.0

Comment: Thanks for the link for 2012 ver. of moderncv. I have added it to the answer.