# How to print name in single line in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm using the banking style of `moderncv` in Overleaf with the 2014 version of Tex Live. I want to give a bit more space for the name/resume title line. I've been able to adjust the font size so it doesn't take up two lines, but I'd rather keep the font size the same and just give more horizontal room for that line.

Similarly, I would also like the option to adjust the width of the columns for longer entries with `/cventry` so they don't run into the dates on the right. But I'm more concerned with my first issue at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the visitors of this page: I suppose this question is related to [Remove blank line in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555321/remove-blank-line-in-moderncv)
. Check out the link for MWE.

Anyway, here is the quite simple solution to add minus kerns before and after the name/title line:

```
\name{\kern-5em{}John}{Doe}
\title{long long long long long Resume title\kern-5em}
```

Result:

[image: result]

---

[NOTE] In the obsolete moderncv 2012 ver. you gave me in the linked question above, the following may be proper:

```
\firstname{\kern-5em{}John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{long long long long long Resume title\kern-5em}
```